# MySql Update query using escaping string array giving error

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have just learnt about SQL injection so I am making my queries a little more safe, everything has worked out so far except when I use update.

```
var sql = 'UPDATE Clients SET LastAccessDate= ? WHERE ClientID= ?';
        var values = [
                       [timeStamp[1], ClientID[1]],//timeStamp=1473674800015, ClientID= 123
                       [timeStamp[2], ClientID[2]],
                       [timeStamp[3], ClientID[3]],
                       [timeStamp[4], ClientID[4]]
                    ];
        connection.query(sql, [values], function(err) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
                console.log("Error updating Last Access times");
            }
            else if(!err){
                connection.end();
            }

        });
```

The connection to the database was done correctly, all column names are correct and arrays for the variables is correct, but I get an error that the syntax is wrong for update and I don't know where to look for the correct answer as my searches have been unsuccessful so far. What is the correct syntax for update and where can I look to find the syntax for other queries? The timestamp is a Bigint and the clientID is a unsigned int. Also ClientID is unique. Using nodejs and mysql database.

Comment: I think it may be that the MYSQL driver is looking for an equal number of placeholder and values. You have 2 placeholders (the "?") yet 8 values. In PHP, the two must always be the same. Not sure about js. Also, you'll most likely need a loop in there to perform the query on all of your value pars.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am actually using the same layout for Insert queries, this setup will loop through the values 2 at a time. Just gives syntax error when i substitute update into it.